# BISON MAP define

Tags: bison

I'm writing in bison and try to save a map of maps
but I have a problem with the union type of map :

```
%union {
    int int_value;                 /* integer value */
    char* string_value;                /* string value */
    void* map_value;             /* map value */
};


assign:     
       TOKEN_VAR '=' '{' Exp "}" {myMap[$1]=$4; mapSave.clear();}       ;

Exp :   TOKEN_MAP {$$=$1;}
        | value{}
        | Exp',' value{}

        ;


value:  stringExpr ':' intExpr {mapSave[$1]=$3;}
        ;
```

so for example I have :

abc={a:1,b:2,c:3}

and I need to save it in the map of maps:
so I have:

```
typedef map<int, string> innerMap;
    typedef map<string, innerMap> mainMap;

    mainMap myMap;

    map<string,int> mapSave;
```

and I get lots of errors:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> > >::mapped_type {aka std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> >}’ and ‘void*’)
       TOKEN_VAR '=' '{' Exp "}" {myMap[$1]=$4; mapForSave.clear();}
                                                 ^
   note: candidate is:
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:264:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::basic_string<char> > >]
           operator=(const map& __x)
           ^
    /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:264:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void*’ to ‘const std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> >&’
```

maybe , someone have an idea to do this ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your bison file includes the declaration:

```
%type <map_value> Exp
```

(Note 1). However, the `map_value` tag is not, in fact, an instance of `std::map`, nor even of `std::map*`. It is a `void*`. So in the statement,

```
myMap[$1]=$4;
```

You are trying to assign a `void*` (`$4`) to a `std::map<int, std::string>` (the `mapped_type` of `myMap`. That's obviously not going to work, because there is no possible way to convert a `void*` to a `std::map` of any type.

And that's exactly what the error message is telling you.

You cannot fix that by making `map_value` a `std::map<int, std::string>` (Note 2) because a `std::map` cannot be a union member, but you could make `map_value` a pointer to such a map. A smart pointer would be better but it can't be a union member either, so you would have to deal with memory management yourself.

I suspect that you really intended to use the global `mapSave` instead of `$4`, though. You could certainly write `myMap[$1] = mapSave;` (but see below; you probably also need to `free($1)`), but that is ugly for a couple of reasons: first, the unnecessary existence of the global `mapSave` and second, the fact that the assignment involves a copy of the recently constructed `std::map`, which can be avoided.

There is also a memory management issue with the `char*` `string_value`. If you are filling in that `yylval` member in your lexical scanner using a (f)lex action like:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*    { yylval.string_value = yytext; /* DON'T DO THIS */
                             return TOKEN_VAR;
                           }
```

then you will find that the string has the wrong value. What you need to do is something like this:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*    { yylval.string_value = strdup(yytext);
                             return TOKEN_VAR;
                           }
```

but then you need to free the copied string once you have created a `std::string` out of it, which means your bison action would have to look something like:

```
value:  stringExpr ':' intExpr { mapSave[$1]=$3;
                                 free($1); /* Free the copied string */
                               }
```

---

#### Notes

1. In general, it's best to include details like that in your question rather than forcing potential answerers to guess. We might guess wrong, in which case the answer will be misleading, or we might simply not bother to try.
2. It's not at all clear to me why the `mapped_type` of `myMap` is `std::map<int, std::string>`. Everything else in the question seems to indicate that it should be `std::map<std::string, int>`.